# Anchor Links within pages

Tags: html, anchor

I have a link that links to domain.com/faq/#fees. How do I get this to scroll down to the Fees section of the FAQ page?

```
<section id="Fees">  // doesn't work
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<section id="fees">` OR link to `domain.com/faq/#Fees`.

It's case sensitive.